# Proxying any URL to a static, untouched URL?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

```
server {
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://other.com/section;
    }
}
```

Currently:

- as expected, `http://127.0.0.1:8000` redirects to `http://other.com/section`,
- however, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/something` redirects to `http://proxy.com/section/something`.

How can I have `http://127.0.0.1:8000/(.*)` to proxy to `http://proxy.com/section` instead of `http://proxy.com/section/(.*)`?

Answer (score 0):

From nginx `proxy_pass` [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass):

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
>
> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:

So, the issue with your configuration is that you are missing the `/` at the end of your `proxy_pass` line. You should use this:

```
proxy_pass http://other.com/section/;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that already and strangely, it doesn't work: `2016/08/02 10:53:16 [debug] 10#10: *2 http proxy header:
"GET /section/something HTTP/1.0
Host: proxy.com
Connection: close`

Comment: Then it is a problem with your other server, you should look into that server's logs to see why it closes the connection.

Comment: Well nginx is still trying to reach `/section/something`

Comment: Ah true, didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
server {
    listen 8000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://other.com/section?; <-- added a question mark
    }
}
```

- `http://127.0.0.1:8000` redirects to `http://other.com/section?`,
- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/something` redirects to `http://proxy.com/section?something`.

That does the trick in my case as the query string will be ignored, but I am still looking for a proper way to do this.

Answer (score -2):

That exactly what **proxy_pass** do.
From the manual page of **nginx**:

If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI

You could try something like that:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://other.com/section permanent;
```

Comment: I think `rewrite` would change the web page address from `127.0.0.1:8000` to `other.com/section`.